# Search for specific string solr

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, solrj

i'm usig Apache Solr. I would like search for a specific text in a string:

for example i use the query

**title:"Hello"** 
and the result are 3 because it search 'Hello' in all titles, 
but i want only one result ---> "Hello"

have I to change the schema.xml? Or is there a specific query that tries to string?

Comment: You want result that contains only Search String("Hello") in title or you want to restrict the number of search result ??

Comment: You get 3 results because there are 3 documents with title field having "Hello" term.

Comment: Yes i want only Search String("Hello"), thanks

Comment: Maybe you need a second, more complete, example. Because why would you want the string *hello* when you search for *hello*? You must have a more comprehensive reason, it would help to know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define title in Solr Schema as below

```
<field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Now `title:"Hello"` will match exactly `Hello`

Comment: did you reload the collection after changing the schema

Comment: @Lucas you need to Index the data again into the solr in order to see the changes that you did.

Comment: Also remember that the search will be case sensitive, so if the actual content is "hello", searching for "Hello" will not match.